# How to view PWA version of a site in firefox web browser

Tags: debugging, firefox, progressive-web-apps

For example we can view the PWA version of suppose Treebo.com in chrome using the toggle device toolbar.In firefox even if we change the viewport to mobile and refresh it still it loads the web version of the website.

Comment: So it sounds like the switch is based on User Agent sniffing - Chrome in device emulation changes its User Agent, resizing Firefox does not change anything. BTW, PWA is also "the web version".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox you have to enter "Responsive Design Mode"

[image: Responsive Design Mode toggle]

And then select a mobile device.

[image: select a mobile device]